# How to get the value of last column cell in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a grid view and added rows dynamically to that grid view i want to get value of cell 5  for the last row

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridinvoice" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gridinvoice_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date"  DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Debit" HeaderText="Debit" SortExpression="Debit"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit" SortExpression="Credit"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Balance" HeaderText="Balance" SortExpression="Balance"></asp:BoundField>
      </Columns>
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
          No records found!
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Italic="False" />
      <RowStyle Font-Names="font-family: 'Bree Serif',serif;" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this work :

```
int LastRow = gridinvoice.Rows.Count-1;
string Balance = gridinvoice.Rows[LastRow].Cells[5].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want to do it on code behind:

```
int lastRowIndex = gridinvoice.Rows.Count - 1;
string value = gridinvoice.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[5].Text;
```

You wanted to access `Balance Column` of `last Row` right?

Answer (score -1):

```
gridinvoice.Rows[gridinvoice.Rows.Count -1].Cells[4].Text
```

Comment: Hey, we are here to teach and learn. Nobody will learn if you just post code without any explanation.

Comment: I usually do but this code is self explanatory. If you look at the other answers it looks like everybody feels the same. What I have missed is the introductory statement :-)

Comment: Agreed. In this case the question is the problem.